# Why does my Horse seem very itchy?

Tags: horses, uk, equipment, equestrian

Me again!

My horse when she comes in from the field is prone to feeling itchy. This is a new development over the past five days.
She rubs her backside up against her haynet and will sometimes kick the door with her front hoof to get someone's attention to scratch her withers and will attempt to point at where she would like to be scratched with her head.

Some things to note:

- She does have remnance of rain scald on her back (just a few scabs
  left to remove.)
- I've recently purchased a new rug for my mare (third
  one in three months :') ) with a slightly heavier weight (200g)

So far I have two theories:

The rug is too heavy and is causing her to sweat or be hotter than usual and this is causing the rainscald areas to get itchy.

There's nothing wrong but she just wants attention and has found that by kicking the door people will give her that attention whether it be negative (telling her to stop) or positive (petting/scratching etc.)

I will be removing the rug again tonight just to be sure the lining on the inside hasn't been damaged. Previously I have found that the outside material is rip-stop but the inside is not; causing there to be holes on the underneath.

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tftDZ.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an actual question to your question? ;) Sorry if it seems nitpicky, but your post contains only explanative text. Without a focused question, it's hard to write a focused answer and someone might invest time and efford for an answer that doesn't really help you with your actual problem.

Comment: @Elmy - Apologies! It was a question to begin with but the site complained it was too short. In making it longer I removed the question 

Comment: I'll answer this. It's not for attention - she is itchy. Can be worms and a number of other things. Can you please put in a pic of her back end where she's rubbing?

Comment: bump - can you post a pic?

Comment: @YvetteColomb - Added some pictures of her rear. It seems there was a rather large hole just above her tail and so that part was wet when I removed the rug so it could be that. The amount of hair that I brushed out was unreal so it could well be a combination. I doubt worms as I check "exit areas" and her poo regularly as well as worming her just before Christmas BUT you never know! She's specifically rubbing either side of her tail (at the base)

Comment: hm, I'd worm her just to cover that base, but it sounds like the wet hole. I can't see anything obvious in the pics. A large hole just above her tail? How big and deep? Can you check the skin in that area? It sounds concerning,

Comment: Yvette Colomb - Sorry the large hole was in regards to the rug not her  I’ve sewn it up now but also ordered wormer incase that doesn’t work. Will update when she stops itching :D

Comment: Did you sort out an answer to this? I can write an answer if you like

Comment: Unfortunately not, she still rubs her tail when she comes in every day. It’s quite odd I can’t pinpoint why she does it. Been through two worming regimes already and multiple rugs but as soon as she comes in she’s straight to rubbing. The only other thing I can think of is the gelding she’s turned out with bites her rump A LOT and maybe this is pulling hairs and making it itchy?

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where you might want to seek a veteriarian's advice if you feel like your horse is tormented by the itching.

Your horse might have parasites (e.g. mites), fungus, an allergy or metabolic defect.

It might also come from strain or molt.

Many horses feel itchy on molt, so if your horse has a soft, shiny, nice coat with smooth skin beneath you might not need to worry to much (all other reasons oftimes lead to skin and coat aberations of which some cannot be seen in pictures).

And yes, it might be the rug and in this case, replace it or even better, don't use one if your horse doesn't necessarily need one. How much degrees (Celsius please) have you recently at your location at day and night?

Comment: I like this answer. It's great to have another horse lover active on the site. We have quite  a few now!

Comment: I usually am on stackoverflow since I changed from horses to computer science, but I am glad if I can help some guys with the knowledge I acquired so far. And stackexchange has a great concept for qualitative answers ;)